# I have no HTTP proxy option on IOS

Tags: ios, settings, proxy

I tried to set up a http proxy

I went to "settings>wi-fi>my_network>i" but there was no http proxy option

It's just DNS and nothing after that

My IOS version: 14.5.1

My device: iphone se (2020)

Comment: I assume you scrolled to the bottom of the settings screen on your network settings? Is your iPhone part of a managed setup?

Comment: Yes, I did and no, it's not. I just wanted to try MITMProxy